# Grouping objects by criteria

Tags: c#

I have a set of objects that contain two dates each. I want to sort them by unique combinations of these two dates. Then I want to set a variable in each object to signify what group it belongs to.

Like one set of dates is group A, another is group B etc.

I am wondering if there is a simple way to do this.

Comment: `"unique combinations of these two dates."` what do you mean by this?

Comment: Say group A could be the object containing January 1st and January 3rd. Then Group B could be the object containing January 1st and January 5th.

Comment: Please post some sample data and the code if you tried anything so far.

Comment: That does not explain much.  You really need to be more clear on what you want to do, you also need to show what you have tried.  SO's expectation is that you have made some attempts and that you show it by telling us what code you tried that did not work.

Comment: how should be constructed group name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you can group by two fields:

```
var groups = collection.GroupBy(i => new { i.DateTime1, i.DateTime2 }, i => i);
```

And after you've grouped the elements, you can set your "group variable":

```
foreach (var group in groups)
{
    foreach (var item in group)
    {
        item.Group = $"Group {group.Key.DateTime1}+{group.Key.DateTime2}";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This question is really vague. But you can always just make a class that has two date members and an enum representing group types.

```
public class DateHolder
{
    public enum DHGroups { A, B }

    public DHGroups Group { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date1 { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date2 { get; set; }

    public void SetGroup()
    {
        // Work with Date1 and Date2 to determine the Group
    }
}
```